# Locking and retrieval strategy for concurrent threads from different hosts

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Scenario:
Two separate hosts running a spring batch app with a cron set to be triggered every 5 minutes.
It reads from the database with the query - "get me records where "running = false"

- locks the first records as "running = true" and proceeds to perform more actions on that record.
  In the meantime if the host2 thread tries to read the record from DB , it should not read the first record since it is alreayd marked as running by host1 thread. But in my case it keeps getting the first record itself and continues to proceed on it.

I've tried using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE but that doesnt seem to do anything for me. Tried OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT , in this case I do get the OptimisticLockingException. However, in my code i do the following

```
while (true) {
        try{
            List<Event> events = eventRepo.findEvents(true);

            for (Event event : events) {
                 execute(event);

            }
            return events.size();

        }catch(Exception e){
            log.debug("Exception found");
            continue;
        }
    }
```

My assupmption here is that the first time it encounters the Optimistic Locking exccepion it will try to re run the query in "findEvents". However, i see that it enters that method and immediately tries to update. No select statments are seen in the logs after the first attempt by host2.